AssertionError while testing forms.py in Django
I tried to test forms.py in Django which has LeadForm class.
Here, is the models.py
class Lead(TimestampedModel):
    """leads for LIVE courses"""

    course = models.ForeignKey(
        LiveCourse, related_name="leads", on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

Here, is the code I used to test.
@pytest.fixture
def valid_course(db):
    return Course.objects.create(name='Design')


@pytest.fixture
def valid_lead_data(valid_course):
    return {
        'full_name': 'john',
        'phone_number': '1234567890',
        'email': 'john@gmail.com',
        'course': valid_course.id,
        'g-recaptcha-response': 'PASSED',
    }

The above code shows AssertionError that the course is not in one of the available choices.
Thanks in advance.

Is that form related to a model? If it is, Can you provide associated model?

Please provide a [mre], to begin with you're very clearly missing the failing test.

Although the cause of your error might be because you're using the wrong model, your foreign key is for LiveCourse while your fixture is creating a Course object.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Why don't you use the "TestCaase" in "tests.py" of django? instead of using pytest decorator?

Note that in valid_course you create Course object, but in the Lead model course field related to LiveCourse model.
